# finding the closest previous sibling that contains .myClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of `<tr>` some of them contain a `<td>` that has `class="myClass"` but some don't. So it looks like something like this.

```
<tr>
<td class="myClass"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

If I'm at a `<tr>`, how do I go up in rows until I hit the closest row that contains a `td.myClass`? Is there a clever way to do this? What I have now is a while loop that checks prev() and if it finds .myClass, it breaks.

Comment: Do you want to actually navigate with js code, or do you just want a set of all the <td>'s that have myclass, as in $('td.myClass') ?

Comment: @joshp, No just the closest one to where I'm at. If I want all `$('td.myClass')` I can simply select it that easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$currentTr.prevAll(':has(td.myClass)').first()
```

Comment: Am I missing something in the jsFiddle example? First it's using lists instead of tables as the OP's question asks for, second it doesn't work on multiple lists.

Comment: If you don't agree with it you may want to edit or remove it.

Comment: I saw it covers the idea of `prevAll()` in general, but anyway, as it causes confusion, I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example, not so great, but works. http://jsfiddle.net/H2k8m/2/ 
1) The td with class "color" will be the selected ones. 
2) Either you can use that or you can directly assign the selected object to some variable and use it outside the function.

HTML :

```
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td class="myClass">Hi</td>
        <td>world</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td class="myClass">1</td>
        <td class="myClass" >2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

CSS :

```
.color {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

table {
    cursor: pointer;
}

tr, td {
    min-width: 50px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("table tr td").click(function() {
        if( $(this).prevAll('[class="myClass"]').length <= 0 ) {
            var parents = $(this).parent().siblings();
            for( i = $(this).parent().index(); i >= 0; i-- ) {
                parents.eq( i ).find(".myClass").last().addClass("color");
                if( parents.eq( i ).find(".myClass").length > 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
         }
        else {
            $(this).prevAll('[class="myClass"]').first().addClass("color");
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that will find the actual closest td with the myClass classname.  If you want the tr, you can simply get the parent of what it finds:

```
var td$ = $("#myTable td.myClass");
$("#myTable td").click(function() {
    td$.removeClass("found");
    var temp$ = td$.add(this);
    var i = temp$.index(this);
    if (i > 0) {
        temp$.eq(i - 1).addClass("found");
    }
});
```

This gets a list of all td's with myClass.  It then adds the clicked on element to that jQuery object (jQuery will sort it into DOM order after adding it).  It then finds the index of the clicked on element in that jQuery object and if it's not the first item, it just gets the item before it which will be the closest td.myClass object before it in the table.

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/XqLzb/